# how to make group of buttons inside scroll view?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I need to make something like this
[image]

the problem is 6 buttons in the middle, how to make it manually by using scroll view? I need to use scroll view since it will be a problem if in landscape mode

here is what I make
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10TBjW3qAaDEGJ_I_EQBPr5anzGcG1-er/view?usp=sharing

the problem is, in iPhone 5s, it seems it can be scrolled horizontally even though I have set width of content view to be the same as scroll view, and in larger phone, it seems not located centrally and not fill the screen

I don't know what went wrong with the auto layout

Comment: Use a collection view instead of a scroll view to set up your buttons.

Comment: after going through your problem . I think best you can do is use collectionView  with Horizontal directions enable .  instead of scrollview
just a suggestion.

Comment: to avoid scrolling set width one content view equal to superView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unzip your project, and open the storyboard to check those constraint. You can change device to `iPhone SE` as the red rectangle marked. I notice that the `Width of Content View` is fixed with `375`. It should be as the same as `the width of Scroll View`.

[image: Before modification]

---

After updating the width of Content View constraint, I remove the `Width:375` constraint, and apply new one that to equal to `the width of Scroll View`. It looks like the following image.

Hope those help you.

[image: After modification]